# construct dataframe from a series of keys and a key:value dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas series of keys and would like to create a dataframe by selecting values from other dataframes.

eg.

```
data_df = pandas.DataFrame({'key' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
                       'value1': [1.1,2,3,4,5,6],
                       'value2': [7.1,8,9,10,11,12]
})
keys = pandas.Series(['a','b','a','c','e','f','a','b','c'])

data_df
#   key value1  value2
#0  a   1.1     7.1
#1  b   2.0     8.0
#2  c   3.0     9.0
#3  d   4.0     10.0
#4  e   5.0     11.0
#5  f   6.0     12.0
```

I would like to get the result like this

```
result
    key value1  value2
0   a   1.1     7.1
1   b   2.0     8.0
2   a   1.1     7.1
3   c   3.0     9.0
4   e   5.0     11.0
5   f   6.0     12.0
6   a   1.1     7.1
7   b   2.0     8.0
8   c   3.0     9.0
```

one way I have successfully done this is by using

```
def append_to_series(key):
    new_series=data_df[data_df['key']==key].iloc[0]
    return new_series
pd.DataFrame(key_df.apply(append_to_series))
```

However, this function is very slow and not clean. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the series into`dataframe` with column name `key`

use [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge `value1,value2`

```
keys = pd.DataFrame(['a','b','a','c','e','f','a','b','c'],columns=['key'])
res = pd.merge(keys,data_df,on=['key'],how='left')

print(res)
```

```
   key  value1  value2
0   a     1.1     7.1
1   b     2.0     8.0
2   a     1.1     7.1
3   c     3.0     9.0
4   e     5.0    11.0
5   f     6.0    12.0
6   a     1.1     7.1
7   b     2.0     8.0
8   c     3.0     9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Create index by `key` column and then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

*Notice*: Necessary unique values of original `key` column.

```
df = data_df.set_index('key').reindex(keys.rename('key')).reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df = data_df.set_index('key').loc[keys].reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
  key  value1  value2
0   a     1.1     7.1
1   b     2.0     8.0
2   a     1.1     7.1
3   c     3.0     9.0
4   e     5.0    11.0
5   f     6.0    12.0
6   a     1.1     7.1
7   b     2.0     8.0
8   c     3.0     9.0
```